# Where to find Software

Tags: windows-10, xampp

Does anyone know where I can find a version of XAMP (or XAMPP) (or phptriad) for a 64-bit Windows-10 pc?  Many helpful sites offer suggestions for downloads of the triad (or a similar package) but, on closer inspection, they are 32-bit versions which will not work on the 64-bit pc.

Answer (score 0):

Right now, 64bit versions of XAMP are only available for Mac & Linux.
I've personally used the 32bit version on my 64bit Windows system and it worked like a charm.

Give it a go :)

Note: 
You can check the versions available for download @ 
[Apache Friends](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html)

Comment: And on a general note, you can always use 32bit programs on 64bit versions of Windows.